# xcode objective c soap xml 3g don't work

Tags: objective-c, xcode, soap, 3g

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];
 NSString *id=@"1";
 NSString *GetExRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<SOAP-     ENV:Envelope \n"
                     "xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" \n"
                     "xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" \n"
                     "xmlns:SOAP-ENC=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\"\n"
                     "SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/\" \n"
                     "xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"> \n"
                     "<SOAP-ENV:Header> \n"
                     "<UserName xmlns=\"CH1\">a1</UserName>\n"
                     "<Password xmlns=\"CH2\">a2</Password>\n"
                     "</SOAP-ENV:Header> \n"
                     "<SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"
                     "<NewsGet xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                     "<id>%@</id> \n"
                     "</NewsGet> \n"
                     "</SOAP-ENV:Body> \n"
                     "</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>\n", id];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https:/www.a.com/Service1.svc"];
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",GetExRequest length]];
 [theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [theRequest addValue: @"http://tempuri.org/IService1/NewsGet"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"Soapaction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [GetExRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if(theConnection)
{
webData = [[NSMutableData data] init];
 }
else
{
 NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
 }
itemArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

 }

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData: (NSData *)data
{
[webData appendData:data];
}
```

Hi there, I have problems with webservice connection on objective-c. On 3G connections, our connections are too slow or not working. But on WiFi, my app works fine. 3G connection is fast, but i cant understand why this slowing appears. Should i do something extra for 3G?

When i put breakpoin this section, On 3G time to time it enters in didReceiveData function. But on wifi, it enters always.

Answer (score 0):

as per my experience in many project your server responding lately may be thats why you are getting late reply on your device in `3G` connection.

so my work around is to change default time out to explicit set timeout for my request.

**check this**

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:40.0];
```

use your timeout for proper response.